# How to make a smaller list of tuples from a large list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-2.7

I have a large list with about 50 or 60 tuples. In the form:

```
a=[('a', 50), ('b', 46), ('c', 41), ('d', 35) ...]
```

I want a new list with only the first 20 tuples in the list. Like:

```
b=[('a', 50), ('b', 46), ('c', 41), ('d', 35) ... ,('aa', 10)]
```

Comment: Please read the documentation and show some evidence that you did any research on this problem before posting questions here. See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using list slicing:

```
b = a[:20]
```